# How to pass list of strings from a Controller to a View ( or maybe it is not on way I try to do it now)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controllers

This is my first MVC app, and I'm wondering is it possible to pass list of a string to a Controller on this way, **and if not I would like to know why it is not** :

What I've tried to do here :

```
public List<string> Index(string id)
{
    ViewBag.Peoples = new List<string>()
    {
        "Joe",
        "John",
        "Jennifer"
    };
    return View();
}
```

This is the error I'm getting :

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

I'm wondering why I'm facing this issue, why I can't pass just list of a strings to Index view?

Comment: `public ActionResult Index(string id)` (not `List<string>`) - and pass the model to the view, not using `ViewBag`

Answer (score 0):

Your return type should be an ActionResult, generated by passing a viewmodel (containing properties such as the list of strings) as the parameter to the view that it should be bound to.

```
public ActionResult Multiple() 
{ 
    if(DateTime.Now.Day % 2 == 0)     
    { 
         return View("Other"); } 
    else 
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    } 
}
```

Excuse formatting, on my mobile.

Tutorial here https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-actionresults/amp/

Answer (score 0):

you can use form collection method

```
    public ActionResult Test(FormCollection collection)
    {
      string results = collection["Blanks"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    ViewBag.Peoples = new List<string>()
    {
        "Joe",
        "John",
        "Jennifer"
    };
    return View();
}
```

Here Problem is that Your method return type is `List<string>` and you have returned `View()` so that is not possible. change method return type `List<string>` to `ActionResult` it should be works. thanks.